# Creating Left and Right Image pair to view with 3D goggles in stereo from DEM or Hillshade?

Tags: dem, lidar, stereo-imagery, stereographic

How does one create the stereo pair for viewing in a program such as [StereoPhoto Maker](http://stereo.jpn.org/eng/stphmkr/index.html)?

I have processed lidar that I'd like to turn into hillshades and then view in this kind of software, with 3D scope goggles, two images on my screen, etc.

I see a lot of questions/answers on how to create a DEM *from* stereo pairs, but am having trouble finding techniques to actually *make the left and right images* from terrain data in or outside of a GIS software...unless I'm missing something obvious, any ideas?